# How remove <header> from WebView on android?

Tags: android, html, webview, jsoup

I'm triyng to showing twitter site on a webView.
how can i remove/dismiss/invisible the header (The "open application" message)?

```
<header class="CoreLayout-header" role="banner"><div class=" AppHeader"><div class="OpenInAppBar u-cf" jsnamespace="OpenInAppBar"><div class="u-containerWithGutter"><a href="twitter://user?screen_name=nba" jsaction="click:openApp" class="OpenInAppBar-link u-textSmall u-inlineBlock">Open application</a><button class="OpenInAppBar-dismiss u-floatRight" aria-label="התעלם" jsaction="click:snooze" type="button"><span class="OpenInAppBar-dismissIcon u-alignMiddle Icon Icon--close" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFwAkAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAAXACQAAAIbjI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyjIFADs="><svg viewBox="0 0 46 72"><use fill="currentcolor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/i/rw/svg/c25636093d431d0e28be32cd59239cf6/icon#icon-close"></use></svg></span></button></div></div><div class=" AppBar u-cf" data-scribe-component="top_bar" jsnamespace="AppBar"><div class="u-containerWithGutter"><h1 class="u-floatLeft"><a class="AppBar-item" aria-label="Twitter" href="/" jsaction="homeNav"><span class="AppBar-icon Icon Icon--twitter" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="><svg viewBox="0 0 72 72"><use fill="currentcolor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/i/rw/svg/c25636093d431d0e28be32cd59239cf6/icon#icon-twitter"></use></svg></span></a></h1><div class="u-floatRight"><a class="AppBar-search AppBar-item" aria-label="חיפוש בטוויטר" href="/search" role="search" jsaction="search"><span class="AppBar-icon Icon Icon--search" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwAJAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAAHAAkAAAIHjI+py+1cAAA7"><svg viewBox="0 0 56 72"><use fill="currentcolor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/i/rw/svg/c25636093d431d0e28be32cd59239cf6/icon#icon-search"></use></svg></span></a></div></div></div><div class=" SignUpBar"><div class="u-containerWithGutter"><div class="SignUpBar-content u-md-size3of4"><div class="Grid Grid--withGutter"><div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><a class="SignUpBar-button u-sizeFull Button Button--textBlue   " href="/signup"><span class="Button-content">sign</span></a></div><div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><a class="SignUpBar-button u-sizeFull Button Button--default   " href="/session/new"><span class="Button-content">Enter</span></a></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="AppHeader-tracking"><img src="https://cert.twitter.com/robots.txt"><img src="https://twitter.com/robots.txt"></div></header>
```

I'm using jsuop library but not have a clue how to remove the header.

Comment: Sorry but i not get it. Can you write me a sample code please?

Comment: Wait a minute. You only want to remove it when it's displayed on an Android device? Or only when it's in a WebView? Also, seeing the other answer, it's not clear if you want to remove the entire header (everything you posted here) or only the "Open application" link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to inject some javascript code in the `onPageFinished` event of the `WebView`, that would remove the header. Something like this:

```
//JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work  
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

//set the WebViewClient before calling loadUrl
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
    {  
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
            "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];" 
            + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
           "})()");  
        }  
    });
```

(code not tested)

Comment: how can i hide footer and Image slider too ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `style="display:none"` to whatever you want hidden.

```html
<header class="CoreLayout-header" role="banner">
  <div class=" AppHeader">
    <div class="OpenInAppBar u-cf" jsnamespace="OpenInAppBar">
      <div class="u-containerWithGutter">
        <a style="display:none" href="twitter://user?screen_name=nba" jsaction="click:openApp" class="OpenInAppBar-link u-textSmall u-inlineBlock">Open application</a>
        <button class="OpenInAppBar-dismiss u-floatRight" aria-label="התעלם" jsaction="click:snooze" type="button"><span class="OpenInAppBar-dismissIcon u-alignMiddle Icon Icon--close" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFwAkAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAAXACQAAAIbjI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyjIFADs="><svg viewBox="0 0 46 72"><use fill="currentcolor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/i/rw/svg/c25636093d431d0e28be32cd59239cf6/icon#icon-close"></use></svg></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" AppBar u-cf" data-scribe-component="top_bar" jsnamespace="AppBar">
      <div class="u-containerWithGutter">
        <h1 class="u-floatLeft"><a class="AppBar-item" aria-label="Twitter" href="/" jsaction="homeNav"><span class="AppBar-icon Icon Icon--twitter" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="><svg viewBox="0 0 72 72"><use fill="currentcolor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/i/rw/svg/c25636093d431d0e28be32cd59239cf6/icon#icon-twitter"></use></svg></span></a></h1>
        <div class="u-floatRight">
          <a class="AppBar-search AppBar-item" aria-label="חיפוש בטוויטר" href="/search" role="search" jsaction="search"><span class="AppBar-icon Icon Icon--search" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwAJAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAAHAAkAAAIHjI+py+1cAAA7"><svg viewBox="0 0 56 72"><use fill="currentcolor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/i/rw/svg/c25636093d431d0e28be32cd59239cf6/icon#icon-search"></use></svg></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" SignUpBar">
      <div class="u-containerWithGutter">
        <div class="SignUpBar-content u-md-size3of4">
          <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
            <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
              <a class="SignUpBar-button u-sizeFull Button Button--textBlue   " href="/signup"><span class="Button-content">sign</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
              <a class="SignUpBar-button u-sizeFull Button Button--default   " href="/session/new"><span class="Button-content">Enter</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="AppHeader-tracking">
    <img src="https://cert.twitter.com/robots.txt">
    <img src="https://twitter.com/robots.txt">
  </div>
</header>
```

Or, alternatively, remove it from the source completely.